# How to re-tag a question?

Tags: support, tags

[This page](https://english.stackexchange.com/privileges/retag-questions) says:

> Click the `retag` menu option under the post.

But the only options I see are `link`, `edit` and `flag`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You're not going wrong. The option is no longer there. Someone's just forgotten to update the documentation accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have the privilege of editing a post, or suggesting an edit, the "retag" link is not shown. This is true for:

- The user who asked the question, which is always able to edit her/his question
- The users with a reputation lower than 500
- The users with a reputation higher than, or equal to [2000](https://english.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit)

For example, on *Ask Different* my reputation is lower than 2000, and for [a question asked from somebody else](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/52575/3598), I see the "retag" link.

[image: screenshot]

On the same site, I don't see the "retag" link for [my own questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/53722/3598).

[image: screenshot]

On *Seasoned Advice*, my reputation is higher than 2000, and [I don't see the "retag" link](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/7707/1229). I just use the "edit" link to edit the tags.

[image: screenshot]

On sites where I am a 10k (or 20k) user, I can use the inline tag editing.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If you hover your mouse on the tags then a link appears:

[image: Mouse hover on the tags to make the "edit tags" link visible]

Click on the link to edit the tags.

This method is only available to users with 10K reps or above.

For other users They have to edit the question and then edit the tags list from there.

Comment: When I hover my cursor over a tag, I see a grey-coloured box which describes the tag (similar to a user's "about me"). I don't see the "edit tags" option.

Comment: But I have found a way. If I edit the question, I get the option to edit the tags.

Comment: That is an option for 10k users; other users are not allowed to inline edit tags.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I did not know that. Thanks.